# converting special string to std::wstring c++

Tags: c++, decode, utf-16

I defined a `const char* s = "\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645"` which should be translated to `std::wstring` as `L"سلام"`. How can I perform this conversion? In other words, I need something similar to [this web site](https://checkserp.com/encode/unicode/), in which its screen shot has been provided below:

[image]

As it can be seen, the term is decoded to `سلام`. I want to write C++ code to perform this same decoding.

Comment: how is your `std::string` encoded?

Comment: `"\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645"` is UTF-16 for `"سلام"`.

Comment: Is the first character in your string a literal backslash followed by a literal `u` and then 4 hex digits?  Or is your first character a utf-16 escape?

Comment: @selbie as you see each \u is followed by for digit.

Comment: @Babak.Abad that is not what selbie asked you. Does your input `std::string` contain just 4 characters `'\u0633'` `'\u0644'` `'\u0627'` `'\u0645'`, or does it contain 24 characters ```'\'``` `'u'` `'0'` `'6'` `'3'` `'3'` ```'\'``` `'u'` `'0'` `'6'` `'4'` `'4'` ```'\'``` `'u'` `'0'` `'6'` `'2'` `'7'` ```'\'``` `'u'` `'0'` `'6'` `'4'` `'5'`? I *suspect* the latter is the case. It makes a BIG difference in how you "decode" it

Comment: This what i found in visual studio `Locals`:  ` 0x00007ff6bae3cb94 "????" ` `const char *`.  I also `updated the question`, please it read it again. I changed the input type for the conversion.

Comment: On the surface, it seems like the OP wants to write a parser for C++ string literals (Unicode escapes supported) for his program (or website). I suspect that's not the OP needs (aka an XY problem).

Comment: @Babak.Abad - here's another way to answer my question. if you just did `cout << s[0] << "\n";` where `s` is your source string, would it print a backslash? Or would it print a random character?

Comment: @selbie the result is `?` on my console (normal windows pc).

Comment: oh ok. So have you considered just doing:   `std::wstring s = (const wchar_t*)s;` That will work on Windows where wchar_t is 16-bit.  Will require a conversion on Mac where wchar_t is 32-bit.

Comment: @selbie it did not work, unfortunately. It tested something like std::wstring s = L"سلام"; . and the result in visual studio is this:                                                
                [0] 1587 'س' wchar_t  #
  [1] 1604 'ل' wchar_t  #
  [2] 1575 'ا' wchar_t  #
  [3] 1605 'م' wchar_t

Comment: Why is `codecvt_utf8_utf16` deprecated without a convenient alternative?

Comment: Maybe because if it is underspecified and broken anyway, it is better to mark them deprecated earlier than later.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use codecvt, though it is deprecated.

```cpp
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

int main() {
    const char* s = "\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645";
    
    std::string ss = s;
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> conv;
    std::wstring ws = conv.from_bytes(ss);
    
    __debugbreak();
    
    return 0;
}
```